# Error while deploying React App on Vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, vercel

I tried deploying my React App on Vercel but i get those error messages:

```
The cli flag --force was set. Skipping build cache download.
Cloning completed: 687.734ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.4.17
Installing dependencies...
yarn install v1.22.17
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
Directory: /vercel/path0
Output:
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next build
info  - Loaded env from /vercel/path0/.env
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: yarn add --dev eslint
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
info  - Using external babel configuration from /vercel/path0/.babelrc
Failed to compile.
../../usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/core.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/version.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyAndLint.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:41863)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequire (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:42364)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:43011)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)
    at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717013
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePreset (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:40447)
../../usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_error.js
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/core.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/version.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyAndLint.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:41863)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequire (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:42364)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:43011)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)
    at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717013
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePreset (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:40447)
./pages/_app.js
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/core.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/version.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyAndLint.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:41863)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequire (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:42364)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:43011)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)
    at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717013
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePreset (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:40447)
./pages/index.js
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/core.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/version.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyAndLint.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:41863)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequire (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:42364)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:43011)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)
    at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717013
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePreset (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:40447)
./pages/product/[slug].js
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/core.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/version.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/events/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyAndLint.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:41863)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequire (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:42364)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:43011)
    at sync (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)
    at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717013
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePreset (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:40447)
> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

I can't deploy on Vercel, any tip on how to fix that?
Thanks in advance.

I'll also leave a link to a video including the full Vercel log with errors highlighted in red: https://www.veed.io/view/218cb302-0a04-406f-84a9-7b5d353a2ffa?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

I tried building and launching the React App on Visual Studio with "yarn run dev" and "yarn run build" and everything works fine, proglems appear while trying to  deploy it on Vercel.